# EventEmitter is not working in Angular5, How can I make it run?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I put 4 hours effort to solve this problem , I examine a lot of codes, although I coded in the same way, nothing has worked for me.

I have parent and child and I want child component to trigger one of methods in parent. Let me show my codes, what is wrong with my code?

**child.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cardMode: CardMode;
  @Input() cardItem: CardModel;

  @Output()
  cardSelected: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

.......
 cardClick(): void {
    this.cardSelected.emit("aaaa");
  }
.......
}
```

**child.html**

```
<a (click) ="cardClick()"> 
     .....
</a>
```

**parent.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
.......
 onCardSelected(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

**parent.html**

```
<app-card [cardItem]="activeCard" [cardMode]="CardMode.Detail"
              (cardSelected) = "onCardSelected($event)" >
 </app-card>
```

When child"s onclick working , after emit("aaaa");  parent`s method is not triggered. Which issue am I missing out?

Comment: This seems textbook `@Output` usage. Could you maybe try to reproduce the problem on stackblitz.com and share it?

Comment: I could not understand what you mean by " @Output usage" ,  ok I will share

Comment: I meant that the code I'm looking seems like it should work.

Comment: Absolutely agree, what are you seeing? A stackblitz.com reproduction of the problem would be helpful!

Comment: Also, this is not necessarily a TypeScript issue; more RxJS, so I'll add that one for you.

Comment: works fine for me, check this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khwmvv

Comment: @nircraft thank you , yes but still I can not make it work on my computer. In stackblitz , it is using Angular 8 but I am using Angular 5

Comment: @ Bjorn 'Bjeaurn' S   thanks but I need in Angular 5.  I have been working for 5 hours but can not able to solve

Comment: @Ozmen The usage didn't change between Angular 5 and 8. I think something that is omitted from your code samples is causing the problem, so we can't help you without seeing the whole code involved :/

Comment: You have a `<a (click)>` handler but are not calling `$event.preventDefault()` so maybe it is triggering a route change.

Comment: @ Reactgular  But  I can successfully call   cardClick(): void {
    this.cardSelected.emit("aaaa");
  }  function.      After this code ,  my parent function is not triggered

Comment: may be your `ParentComponent` is not the  parent for the `app-card`? How does your DOM structure look where `app-card` is used?

Comment: @nircraft  how can it happen? I am using child directive in parent html so it makes my parent component to be parent for child(app-card)

Comment: It can happen if your child is wrapped under another component. EX: `<parent><child-a><child-emitting-event><child-emitting-event></child-a></parent>` This means parent for the child emitting event is `<child-a>` not `<parent>`

Comment: @nircraft I have 2 app-card in my page and I mistakely put (cardSelected) to wrong one:)